# Hashing Function for Three Signed Integers

Tags: c++, hash

I'm trying to use an unordered_map with three signed integers as a key (this is because I wish to use tbb's concurrent_unordered_map).

I put together this little (3x16-bit => 64-bit) function:

```
// to hash

int64_t result = int16_t(x);

result = int64_t(result << 16) + int16_t(y);
result = int64_t(result << 16) + int16_t(z);

// from hash

int16_t x_ = int16_t(result >> 32);
int16_t y_ = int16_t(result >> 16);
int16_t z_ = int16_t(result & 0xFFFF);
```

This isn't working, what mistake have I made here?

My distribution of numbers is such that negative or positive number closer to zero is more likely (typically less than +/- 2^8), but I would like to extend this to work with a range up to 2^32, rather than my 2^16 example here. Ideally, I'm looking for as very few collisions within the typical range and preferably a simple algorithm. Any suggestions?

Comment: How does it not work?

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that you are performing bit manipulations and adding on signed numbers. If the numbers are negative, the addition operation will translate into a subtraction. It will be difficult to tease out the correct original values after that happens.

Consider:

```
int16_t x = -1, y = 2, z = -3;
int64_t result = x;          // result: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
result = (result << 16) + y; // result: FFFFFFFFFFFF0000 + 0002
result = (result << 16) + z; // result: FFFFFFFF00020000 - 0003
return result;               // result: FFFFFFFF0001FFFD
```

Thus, while `-1` and `-3` has been preserved, the result of the subtraction has reduced `2` to `1`.

Instead, you should limit your operations on unsigned values. With unsigned values, `+` and `|` will be equivalent in your code since you are adding into the part of the number that is being `0` filled.

```
int64_t hash () {
    uint64_t result = uint16_t(x_);
    result = (result << 16) + uint16_t(y_);
    result = (result << 16) + uint16_t(z_);
    return result;
}
```